# how can I test a data set whether it obeys super gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I got a data set,I used gaussian mixture to model it.And I used BIC(Bayesian Information Criterions) to get the best number of components.However, the data set seems not obey gaussian distribution,but super gaussian distribution,and BIC doesn't work,it gave the wrong answer.So, I need to verify my guess.
The question is how can I test my data set whether it obeys super gaussian distribution. Maybe, some function you konw can sovle this problem,or some method to get the shape parameter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAii5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simulation? Which you have already generated then simply use a goodness of fit test

Comment: yes, ns3 simulation, I got the delay. And I cant control its generation.

Comment: I would just say replace BIC with the goodness of fit test. I agree BIC is very cool, but if it is not working use something much simpler